# Using maven-clean-plugin with m2e

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, maven-clean-plugin

I use here Eclipse with m2e plugin. If I do a project clean, it doesn't do anything.

On my experiments, I see as if m2e simply weren't wired into the eclipse project cleaning option.

I've tried to set up in `lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml`, but it didn't work. If I understand this well, maybe a clean can't be set up here, because cleaning is not considered as part of a project lifecycle from the viewpoint of the eclipse.

So, is there any way to do a simple `mvn clean` from eclipse on a project cleanup?

(The ideal solution didn't require to start a new jvm, and all run inside of the eclipse process.)

Comment: So you want an Eclipse project->clean to trigger a `mvn clean` operation? If so, why is this important to you, rather than just running a `mvn clean` from within Eclipse when you feel the need?

Comment: When I run maven clean in my Eclipse I can see that it deletes target folder, but then re-creates it and restores resources only in it

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Maybe it is because you turned auto-build on. I don't. Eclipse java builder deletes all target folders, which gives the interesting question, why should a project cleaning called by a _java_ _compiling_ _subsystem_. And there are a very big legion of such interessant questions around eclipse.

Comment: @Duncan Yes, I could do these things, but I am really wondering, why can a such _basic_ functionality so _hard_ to set up. A well known Java IDE, and it can't simply clean up a project?

Comment: @PeterHorvath In my Eclipse install, if I do a project->clean (with automatic building disabled), it deletes all class files from `target`, but leaves the `classes` and `test-classes` directories in place. Is that the behaviour you see?

Comment: @Duncan No, because I have some additional things in target as well, and I want also them to be deleted. If I call mvn clean from the command line, it deletes everything properly. This is what I try to do from m2e as well.

Comment: @PeterHorvath Well, I would think the correct way to do this from m2e is to do right-click, Run As > Maven clean. The fact that m2e isn't integrated into Project>clean is perhaps unfortunate, but I doubt there's a way around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lastest version of the m2e plugin, on Luna, you can display what Maven will do:

[image: Eclipse Preference]

This explains why the clean step is never called.

And sadly, it is unsupported in default Eclipse clean, but you can also invoke Maven from Eclipse using *Run As > Maven clean*.